# Vibration works fine, but sound does not on android

Tags: android

I want to apply a vibration and sound at the same time.
The vibration works fine, but the sound does not work.
 I am getting the sound as an mp3.

How would I solve this issue?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"Get Ready Bus is Near",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Initializing instance of Vibrator.
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // Initializing instance of MediaPlayer.
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    // Starting Vibration
    v.vibrate(2000);

    try {
        // Setting the source of audio file.
        //String path = "android.resource://"+"com.example.myproject"+"/raw/"+audioFile;


mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,Uri.parse("android.resource://"+"com.example.fahad.finalyearprojectlayout"+"/raw/"+"sound.mp3"));  // Fill the information accordingly.
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        // playing audio.
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello. Did my answer help you fix the problem? Is it working now?

Comment: no it did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **different, shorter way** for how you can create a `mediaPlayer`:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
```

So now, this is what your code should look like. You do not need the `try` or `catch` blocks:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
v.vibrate(2000);
```

Try starting the `mediaPlayer` before you start the vibration. If this doesn't work, make sure that you have the sound turned on in your device. If there are still problems, post the new problem below. However, if you have enabled sounds and vibrations for your app, I do not see why it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me

```
public void playNotificationSound() {
    try {
        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/sound");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```